# What is the verb, synonym of stuck, that describes when an object is located between two other objects?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:
"The door was ________ between two bookshelves"

Comment: More context might help with this. Something can be "Lodged" between two things, but that might not make sense depending on the way in which the door is stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The door was ***wedged*** between two bookshelves."

> [wedge (1)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/wedge)
>   VERB
>
> 1. *[with object]* Fix in position using a wedge.
>      *[with object and complement]* *‘the door was wedged open’*
> 2. *[with object and adverbial]* Force into a narrow space.
>      *‘I wedged the bags into the back seat’*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

As the second meaning indicates, if something is *wedged* there is a sense of it being forced into position. Strictly speaking, you would not normally take a door and force it into its location between two bookshelves - door frames don't tend to be mobile. However, the word is often used metaphorically, for example to describe a tightness of fit (which suits your example sentence) or being forced to choose between competing social or political objectives (e.g. a good policy outcome vs good public opinion).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is ***JAMMED***.

According to  Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
 (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jam) :

***jam***

intransitive verb

- to become blocked, wedged, or stuck fast

// The line  jammed and the boat hung useless.